# What is the difference between declaring global and local variables in C using MPLAB?

Tags: c, mplab

When I execute this program, the led blinks for 1s, then 2s, then loops:

```
#include <htc.h>
#include <pic16f877.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4e6

int count;
int check(int count);

void main(void){
    count = 0;
    TRISD = 0xBF;
    count=check(count);
    count=check(count);
}

int check(count){
    if(count == 0){
        /* blink an led for 1s */
        ++count;
    }else if(count == 1){
        /* blink an led for 2s */
        ++count;
    }
}
```

But when I execute this program, 2 things happen:

1. If I execute this program right after I had executed the previous one, the led blinks for 1s, then 2s then stays off.
2. If I execute this program at any other time, once it's not right after the previous one, the led stays off; doesn't even blink.

   ```
   #include <htc.h>
   #include <pic16f877.h>

   #define _XTAL_FREQ 4e6

   int check(int count);
   int count = 0;

   void main(void){
       TRISD = 0xBF;
       count=check(count);
       count=check(count);
   }

   int check(count){
       if(count == 0){
           /* blink an led for 1s */
           ++count;
       }else if(count == 1){
           /* blink an led for 2s */
           ++count;
       }
   }
   ```

So I am wondering what this behaviour has to do with me declaring my variables locally vs globally.

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled. Inside `check()` the variable `count` is not the global one: it is a local variable originated from the argument list.

Comment: The function `int check(int count);` is missing a return statement `return count;`

Comment: The line:  `int check(count){` should be `int check(int count){`, and as pmg has noted, the `count` passed in that argument is _not_ the same as the global `count` declared at the top of your program.  (which by the way does make for bad readability, and provides a very effective confusion factor)  Suggest changing function argument from `count` to `c`, or `ct`.  Anything but `count`.

Answer (score 1):

For all practical purposes, the two programs are completely equivalent. You do not declare variables locally vs. globally; the count variable is global in both programs. The only difference is that the count variable is set to zero in the first program by an instruction. But it was already zero because it is global and global variables are initialized to zero at load time. If you leave out the count = 0 statement from the first program they have become identical.

As they are identical but show different behavior, the problem must be in the mplab emulator. Use the step feature of the emulator/IDE to check the value of count in the check function.

All suggestions in the comments to your question improve the code but none are required:

- a parameter without a type is an int by defaut. So the count parameter is an int;
- a return statement would ensure the right value is returned, but the register in which the function return value is carried apparently still holds the incremented value of count, in Intel assembler this is the ax register:

`mov ax, [count]
inc ax
mov [count], ax`